# Fatal error: index out of Range when trying to access models array contents inside collectionView Function

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to load user information and display on my ProfileViewController. I retrieve the information from the database and append them to an array of user models. When i print the contents of the array in the loadUserInfo function, it shows the correct information, however when i try to display them in the viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind function i get Index out of range error. And when I try to print the contents it shows that there is nothing in the models array. To display the user information I use ProfileInfoHeaderCollectionReusableView that I made. It uses a configure function where i pass the user object and displays the user's first and last name and their profile photo. The information should be displayed in a label and ImageView that are defined in the ProfileInfoHeaderCollectionReusableView class.

```
final class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var collectionView: UICollectionView?
    
    private var database = Database.database().reference()
    
    var models = [Userr]()
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "Profile"
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        configureNavigationBar()
        loadUserInfo()
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 1, bottom: 0, right: 1)
        let size = (view.width-4)/3
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: size, height: size)
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        
        //Cell
        collectionView?.register(PhotoCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: PhotoCollectionViewCell.identifier)
        
        // headers
        collectionView?.register(ProfileInfoHeaderCollectionReusableView.self,
                                 forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader,
                                 withReuseIdentifier: ProfileInfoHeaderCollectionReusableView.identifier)
        collectionView?.register(ProfileTabsCollectionReusableView.self,
                                        forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader,
                                        withReuseIdentifier: ProfileTabsCollectionReusableView.identifier)

        
        collectionView?.delegate = self
        collectionView?.dataSource = self
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return
        }
        
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        collectionView?.frame = view.bounds
    }
    
    private func loadUserInfo(){
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        print("UID for ProfileVc: ",uid!)
        database.child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let username = value["username"] as? String ?? ""
                let firstName = value["firstName"] as? String ?? ""
                let lastName = value["lastName"] as? String ?? ""
                let profilePic = value["profileImageUrl"] as! String
                let user = Userr(username: username, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, profilePhoto: profilePic)
                self.models.append(user)
            }
            print("models: ",self.models[0])
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    

}

extension ProfileViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 0
        }
      //  return userposts.count
        return 30
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // let model = userPosts[indexPath.row]
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PhotoCollectionViewCell.identifier,
                                                      for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell
        //cell.configure(with: model)
        cell.configure(debug: "test")
        return cell
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        
        guard kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader else {
            return UICollectionReusableView()
        }
        
        if indexPath.section == 1 {
            // tabs header
            let tabControlHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: ProfileTabsCollectionReusableView.identifier, for: indexPath) as! ProfileTabsCollectionReusableView
            tabControlHeader.delegate = self
            return tabControlHeader
        }
        
        let profileHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: ProfileInfoHeaderCollectionReusableView.identifier, for: indexPath) as! ProfileInfoHeaderCollectionReusableView
        profileHeader.delegate = self
        //let user = models[indexPath.row]
        print("models content: ",self.models[0]) //here is the line that get fatal error
        //profileHeader.configure(user: models[indexPath.row])// this is the configure function that is used to display the user information in a label and imageView
        return profileHeader
    }
 
    
    
}
```

Comment: This is most likely an asynchronous issue, you are trying to access the array before the data has finished downloading in loadUserInfo

Answer (score 0):

First, set your collection view's frame once, ideally in `loadView` since it appears that you're constructing the view programmatically—don't do it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (this method gets called too late and may be called multiple times).

Second, you should attempt your database call in `viewWillAppear` and not `viewDidLoad` because if there is a synchronous return (such as when the database is operating offline), the collection view may not display the data.

Third, you never reload the collection view in this code after the database fetch is parsed. How does the collection view know to display the data? After you've filled your array, call `collectionView.reloadData()`.

Fourth, remember to account for sections in the collection-view delegate in every method, not just where you return cells.

```
final class ProfileViewController: UIViewController  {
    private var collectionView: UICollectionView?
    private let database = Database.database().reference()
    private var models = [Userr]()
    
    /* You're doing this programmatically; therefore,
       add subviews here. And don't call super on this
       method. */
    override func loadView() {
        addCollectionView()
    }
    
    /* After you've loaded the view in loadView,
       do any post work here (i.e. adding notification
       observers, post-view configuration, etc. */
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() // do call super
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        loadUserInfo()
    }
    
    private func addCollectionView() {
        // configure collection view and then add to view here
    }
    
    private func loadUserInfo() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            return
        }
        database.child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let username = value["username"] as? String ?? ""
                let firstName = value["firstName"] as? String ?? ""
                let lastName = value["lastName"] as? String ?? ""
                let profilePic = value["profileImageUrl"] as! String
                let user = Userr(username: username, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, profilePhoto: profilePic)
                
                self.models.append(user)
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

extension ProfileViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return 0
            
        case 1:
            return userposts.count
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 1:
            let model = userPosts[indexPath.row]
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PhotoCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell
            
            cell.configure(with: model)
            return cell
        default:
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        guard kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader else {
            return UICollectionReusableView()
        }
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            let user = models[indexPath.row]
            let profileHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: ProfileInfoHeaderCollectionReusableView.identifier, for: indexPath) as! ProfileInfoHeaderCollectionReusableView
            
            profileHeader.delegate = self
            profileHeader.configure(user: models[indexPath.row])
            return profileHeader
            
        case 1:
            let tabControlHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: ProfileTabsCollectionReusableView.identifier, for: indexPath) as! ProfileTabsCollectionReusableView
            tabControlHeader.delegate = self
            return tabControlHeader
        default:
            return UICollectionReusableView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually `userposts.count` and `userposts` aren't being used, i commented them out and deleted its declaration but forgot to delete the comments. But even after i did all the steps u mentioned above the models array is empty when trying to access it in `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` but showing values when i print it in the `loadUserInfo` function

Comment: @NotACoder I made some edits that should point you in the right direction.